# The relationship between DataTables in DataSet: can we check if the parent is so and so?

Tags: c#, xml, ado.net

I loaded a complicated XML file with lots of data where there are complex level of nested elements. The `DataSet.ReadXml()` load all that nicely and I can loop through all the nodes.

Essentially each node is picked as DataTable with attributes as column names.

Now I can iterate through ALL these elements/DataTables in a linear fashion like this:

```
    foreach( DataTable curDT in DS.Tables)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Table name: {0}",curDT.TableName);
        Console.WriteLine("Columns Count: {0}", curDT.Columns.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Rows Count: {0}", curDT.Rows.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Container: {0}", curDT.Container);

        Console.WriteLine("columns =>");

        foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in curDT.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataColumn.ColumnName);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

But these DataTables or elements have complex nested relationships with each other (one is inside another).

When I use `WriteXml()` giving a new file name, it recreates the file correctly.

My exact question is there is no apparent relationship between the `DataSet.Tables` list so how is it able to place all cumulative DataTables in one linear list yet they reproduce the xml file correctly. Also I want to check if the parent of so-and-so is this!

**Update**

I am parsing 15000 long STIG xml file which available online but I will just put the start of it if that helps.

```
<Benchmark xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cpe="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" id="Windows_10_STIG" xml:lang="en" xsi:schemaLocation="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/xccdf-1.1.4.xsd http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0 http://cpe.mitre.org/files/cpe-dictionary_2.1.xsd" xmlns="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1">
  <status date="2020-06-15">accepted</status>
  <title>Windows 10 Security Technical Implementation Guide</title>
  <description>The Windows 10 Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG) is published as a tool to improve the security of Department of Defense (DoD) information systems. Comments or proposed revisions to this document should be sent via e-mail to the following address: disa.stig_spt@mail.mil.</description>
  <notice id="terms-of-use" xml:lang="en">Developed_by_DISA_for_the_DoD</notice>
  <reference href="https://cyber.mil/">
    <dc:publisher>DISA</dc:publisher>
    <dc:source>STIG.DOD.MIL</dc:source>
  </reference>
  <plain-text id="release-info">Release: 23 Benchmark Date: 17 Jun 2020</plain-text>
  <version>1</version>
  <Profile id="MAC-1_Classified">
    <title>I - Mission Critical Classified</title>
    <description>&lt;ProfileDescription&gt;&lt;/ProfileDescription&gt;</description>
    <select idref="V-63319" selected="true" />
    <select idref="V-63321" selected="true" />
    <select idref="V-63323" selected="true" />
    <select idref="V-63325" selected="true" />
 </Profile>
  <Group id="V-63319">
    <title>WN10-00-000005</title>
    <description>&lt;GroupDescription&gt;&lt;/GroupDescription&gt;</description>
    <Rule id="SV-77809r3_rule" severity="medium" weight="10.0">
      <version>WN10-00-000005</version>
      <title>Domain-joined systems must use Windows 10 Enterprise Edition 64-bit version.</title>
      <description>&lt;VulnDiscussion&gt;Features such as Credential Guard use virtualization based security to protect information that could be used in credential theft attacks if compromised. There are a number of system requirements that must be met in order for Credential Guard to be configured and enabled properly. Virtualization based security and Credential Guard are only available with Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit version.&lt;/VulnDiscussion&gt;&lt;FalsePositives&gt;&lt;/FalsePositives&gt;&lt;FalseNegatives&gt;&lt;/FalseNegatives&gt;&lt;Documentable&gt;false&lt;/Documentable&gt;&lt;Mitigations&gt;&lt;/Mitigations&gt;&lt;SeverityOverrideGuidance&gt;&lt;/SeverityOverrideGuidance&gt;&lt;PotentialImpacts&gt;&lt;/PotentialImpacts&gt;&lt;ThirdPartyTools&gt;&lt;/ThirdPartyTools&gt;&lt;MitigationControl&gt;&lt;/MitigationControl&gt;&lt;Responsibility&gt;&lt;/Responsibility&gt;&lt;IAControls&gt;&lt;/IAControls&gt;</description>
      <reference>
        <dc:title>DPMS Target Windows 10</dc:title>
        <dc:publisher>DISA</dc:publisher>
        <dc:type>DPMS Target</dc:type>
        <dc:subject>Windows 10</dc:subject>
        <dc:identifier>2885</dc:identifier>
      </reference>
      <ident system="http://iase.disa.mil/cci">CCI-000366</ident>
      <fixtext fixref="F-69237r2_fix">Use Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit version for domain-joined systems.</fixtext>
      <fix id="F-69237r2_fix" />
      <check system="C-64053r3_chk">
        <check-content-ref name="M" href="DPMS_XCCDF_Benchmark_Windows_10_STIG.xml" />
        <check-content>
          Verify domain-joined systems are using Windows 10 Enterprise Edition 64-bit version.

          For standalone systems, this is NA.

          Open "Settings".

          Select "System", then "About".

          If "Edition" is not "Windows 10 Enterprise", this is a finding.

          If "System type" is not "64-bit operating system…", this is a finding.
        </check-content>
      </check>
    </Rule>
  </Group>
```

The file goes on and on. I have provided the start of the file in way it represents the complexity.

Comment: In order to answer it would be good to have an example of the XML data you're parsing, whether fake data or re-created that will help you get an answer.

Comment: @Jimithus I am parsing stigs XML file, this is 15000 lines files available online in zip folder but I will post the start of it if that helps.

Comment: Even if you only have 2 elements of it that show the complexity, it will help.

Comment: Use excel workbook to design you dataset.  Each sheet of the workbook will be a different datatable.  The header rows will be the columns of your datatable.  For each file you will need to link the worksheet (datatable) by a common key like the filename or property inside the xml file.   I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I used Xml Linq to parse xml to keep the number of levels small.  Using xml linq you can combine descendant into one object.  I also used classes instead of table.   See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_10/2020-06-15/MAC-3_Sensitive/xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XElement benchmark = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = benchmark.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace nsDc = benchmark.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dc");

            Header header = new Header(ns, nsDc, benchmark);
            Profiles profiles = new Profiles(ns, benchmark);
            Group groups = new Group(ns, nsDc, benchmark);

            
        }
    }
    public class Header
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string notice { get; set; }
        public string publisher { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string releaseinfo { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }

        public Header(XNamespace ns, XNamespace nsDc, XElement benchmark)
        {
            status = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "status");
            date = (DateTime)benchmark.Element(ns + "status").Attribute("date");
            title = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "title");
            description = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "description");
            notice = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "notice");
            publisher = (string)benchmark.Descendants(nsDc + "publisher").FirstOrDefault();
            source = (string)benchmark.Descendants(nsDc + "source").FirstOrDefault();
            releaseinfo = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "plain-text");
            version = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "version");
        }
    }
    public class Profiles
    {
        public static List<Profiles> ProfileList { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<Profile> profiles { get; set; }

        public Profiles() { }
        public Profiles(XNamespace ns, XElement benchmark)
        {
            List<XElement> xProfiles = benchmark.Elements(ns + "Profile").ToList();
            ProfileList = new List<Profiles>();
            foreach (XElement xProfile in xProfiles)
            {
                Profiles Profile = new Profiles();
                ProfileList.Add(Profile);
                Profile.id = (string)xProfile.Attribute("id");
                Profile.title = (string)xProfile.Element(ns + "title");
                Profile.description = (string)xProfile.Element(ns + "description");
                Profile.profiles = xProfile.Elements(ns + "select").Select(x => new Profile()
                {
                    idref = (string)x.Attribute("idref"),
                    selected = (Boolean)x.Attribute("selected")
                }).ToList();
            }
        }

    }
    public class Profile
    {
        public string idref { get; set; }
        public Boolean selected { get; set; }
    }
    public class Group
    {
        public static List<Group> GroupList { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Rule rule { get; set; }

        public Group() { }
        public Group(XNamespace ns, XNamespace nsDc, XElement benchmark)
        {
            List<XElement> xGroups = benchmark.Elements(ns + "Group").ToList();
            GroupList = new List<Group>();
            foreach (XElement xGroup in xGroups)
            {
                Group group = new Group();
                GroupList.Add(group);
                group.id = (string)xGroup.Attribute("id");
                group.title = (string)xGroup.Element(ns + "title");
                group.description = (string)xGroup.Element(ns + "description");
                XElement xRule = xGroup.Element(ns + "Rule");
                group.rule = new Rule();
                group.rule.id = (string)xRule.Attribute("id");
                group.rule.severity = (string)xRule.Attribute("severity");
                group.rule.weight = (decimal)xRule.Attribute("weight");
                group.rule.version = (string)xRule.Element(ns + "version");
                group.rule.title = (string)xRule.Element(ns + "title");
                group.rule.description = (string)xRule.Element(ns + "description");


                group.rule.idents = xRule.Elements(ns + "idents").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
                group.rule.fixtext = (string)xRule.Element(ns + "fixtext");
                group.rule.fixref = (string)xRule.Element(ns + "fixtext").Attribute("fixref");
                group.rule.fix = (string)xRule.Element(ns + "fix").Attribute("id");

                XElement xReference = xRule.Element(ns + "reference");
                group.rule.reference = new Reference();
                group.rule.reference.title = (string)xReference.Element(nsDc + "title");
                group.rule.reference.publisher = (string)xReference.Element(nsDc + "publisher");
                group.rule.reference.type = (string)xReference.Element(nsDc + "type");
                group.rule.reference.subject = (string)xReference.Element(nsDc + "subject");
                group.rule.reference.identifier = (string)xReference.Element(nsDc + "identifier"); 


            }
        }
    }
    public class Rule
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string severity { get; set; }
        public decimal weight { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<string> idents { get; set; }
        public string fixref { get; set; }
        public string fixtext { get; set; }
        public string fix { get; set; }
        public Reference reference { get; set; }

    }
    public class Reference
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string publisher { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing your approach. Does this work for all revisions? I am not sure how much the format of xml changes (contents sure) between revisions. I want to create app where I can add my own comments to each STIG yet maintain them for every new revision.

Comment: There is a schema which can be used to create the c# classes.  When the schema changes my code may not work.  There are tools like xsd.exe which will automatically take the schema and create classes.  But using the tool will create more layers of classes.  I only have 6 classes.

Comment: I am trying this approach now and I can read the `id` in the `<Group> tag` but `<title>` and `<description>` comes out null. Were you reading all these fields right you have in the code? Thanks!

Comment: The data is in static members of the class.  So you do not access using an instance of the class.   Use Group.GroupList and Profiles,ProfileList

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing but the `title` and `description` values in the class are null but `id` does have correct value. `id` is an attribute the other two are child elements of the `<group>`, seems like does something with that maybe.

Comment: "ns" is missing in two statements :                 group.title = (string)xGroup.Element(ns + "title");
                group.description = (string)xGroup.Element(ns + "description");

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Need to work on the some of the more nested items later but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah glorious STIGs.  But you're question is how does it do it?  Well well-formed XML is parse-able and why they can release 15000+lines as such in an XML to be parsed and utilized.

As far as if it's linear or jagged, it's linear, meaning it will process it from start to end as you have it.  If that XML file had/has 1 invalid part, it wouldn't be read-able.  You can test this by removing a tag somewhere.  It should throw an exception.

If you're looking for a way not to load it all into memory, given the size, check out this SO answer: [Loading large XML on DataSet (OutOfMemory Exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36297630/398519).  If that wasn't the reasoning behind your question, then let us know and we can see if we can figure out what you're after.

Comment: Well I am trying to make sense of it over all like why does it report 3 columns `plaint-text` DataTable with columns id, plain-text_Text and Benchmark_Id. The last one is not in the node. By my exact question is there is no relationship between the `DataSet.Tables` list so how is it able to place all cumulative DataTables in one linear list yet they reproduce the xml file correctly. Also I want to check if the parent of so-and-so is this!

Comment: @zar, I will see if I can compose a more complete answer for you tomorrow.  I'd also add that as an edit to your original question incase others might have an answer for you.

Comment: Sure I updated the question to make it clear.