# Can DataSet be loaded into XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I see code example from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/performing-an-xpath-query-on-a-dataset) how to convert `DataSet` object into `XmlDataDocument`to work with XML better but this class is going to be depreicated.

It  means we should perhaps work with `XmlDocument` class but can we convert a `DataSet` into `XmlDocument`?

This is the part of the code of interest: (basically I want to extract certain nodes)

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(dataSet);

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(  
  "descendant::Customers[*/OrderDetails/ProductID=43]");  
  
DataRow dataRow;  
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in nodeList)  
{  
  dataRow = xmlDoc.GetRowFromElement((XmlElement)xmlNode);  
  if (dataRow != null)  
    Console.WriteLine(dataRow[0]);  
}
```

Comment: Every XML is different.  Without seeing sample of xml I can't tell what methods are needed to parse the xml data.

Comment: It's the same as XML that I posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65333925/841330) question but I haven't even been able to get to the xml part here since I am getting null reference exception. I thought this would be nice way to load a particular section of data from XML like in this case `Benchmark/Group`

Comment: Are you using my answer from the link?  Yo can use the DataSet Method ReadXml :             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(fileName)  The read xml does not work well on XML that have lots of levels of hierarchy.  So I think you want to use my code to parse xml and then load the parsed data into a DataSet. Or modify my code to put parsed xml into a DataSet instead of classes.

Comment: @zar - the XML from that question is truncated.  And even if I add the missing two nodes at the end, it can't be loaded into a `DataSet`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/gIwE73.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)?  `DataSet` and `DataTable` have fairly rich tools for running queries directly, see [Query datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/query-datasets?view=vs-2019), [Cross-Table Queries (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/cross-table-queries-linq-to-dataset),

Answer (score 1):

You can write directly to an `XmlDocument` by [creating an `XPathNavigator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createnavigator?view=net-5.0) for the document then [writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=net-5.0) the `DataSet` to it directly [`AppendChild()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.appendchild?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XPath_XPathNavigator_AppendChild) like so:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
using (var writer = navigator.AppendChild())
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(writer);
}
```

However, if you are rewriting your code anyway, you should consider upgrading to [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-5.0) from [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) which easily supports LINQ queries as well as XPath queries:

```
var doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(writer);
}
```

Either option will be more performant than serializing the `DataSet` to an XML string then parsing the string.

Notes:

- Unlike [`XmlDataDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldatadocument?view=net-5.0#remarks) there is no dynamic link maintained between the `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` and the `DataSet`.  Changes to one are not reflected in the other after creation.
- You might consider whether reading XML into both a `DataSet` and `XDocument` / `XmlDocument` is really required.  Consider simplifying your design by using one or the other, but not both.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3kfFga).

Comment: Yes, it's a new code so the LINQ to XML method sounds good but in part doing it to learning XML/C# better too. I want to load XML file and make changes to it and resave it. That should be okay right maintaining XML document with C# and presenting only applicable data to user where they can make changes and save back to XML? Unless for some reasons if XML file is used largely just to load data.

Comment: If you want to create an app that loads, modifies, then saves back some XML, then LINQ to XML is a good choice.  It's a bit more performant than `XmlDocument` and the handling of namespaces is just easier.  It's also good for learning LINQ as well as XPath.  But as far as *maintaining XML document with C# and presenting only applicable data to user where they can make changes and save back* goes that's a pretty broad requirement, we would need to no more details about your required UI to recommend anything.

Comment: Yes this would be good way to learning LINQ and XPath, that's a goal. Alongside, I also want to create an app where I display stigs items that are provided in XML (I provided a sample file in this [post]()). The DoD site that provides these doesn't have <comment> tag (which makes sense). I want to inject this <comment> tag where user can save their comments about each stig item. This is why I want to save it.

Comment: My strategy is when I read the stig file, the <comment> tag obviously doesn't exist so C# code would read null for comment but when user saves the files, the <comment> tag will be saved in the items now containing user comments if any. That's my plan. Fair enough?

Comment: I disagree with the responses above.  A DataTable is a two dimensions object and a DataSet is a list of multiple DataTables.  You xml is not 2-D so you cannot use one standard object to read your complex XML.  I already did the parsing of your XML into 2-D classes in your previous posting.  Now all you have to do is to take my parsing and put into Tables.  The suggestions above are just repeating what I already have done.